# What is the meaning of this syntax in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a library code that has the following function definition

`def __init__(self, config: 'Configuration') -> None:`

The syntax is valid for Python 3 but invalid for Python 2.7. So my question is what is the meaning of the **config: 'Configuration'** and **-> None** in the above code?

Comment: They are [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: Those are type annotations. Basically no impact on the code just makes it clear what to expect. Here `__init__` expects a Configuration as `config` and returns `None`